# Error in css and js in child theme in Magento 1

Tags: javascript, css, parent-child-theme, custom-theme

I'm having a problem loading style sheets and scripts. I created a child theme, and I did not add any css or js to it. Even so, the magento looks for them in the son theme instead of the father. I'll try to explain better in the code

> design/frontend/custom_theme/default/etc/theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

**This is the structure of the child theme:**

> app/design/frontend/{packageName}/{themeName}/etc
>   app/design/frontend/{packageName}/{themeName}/etc/theme.xml
>   app/design/frontend/{packageName}/{themeName}/layout
>   app/design/frontend/{packageName}/{themeName}/layout
>   app/design/frontend/{packageName}/{themeName}/template

**Here is the setting in the panel:**

[image]

Note that I did not overwrite any parent theme files. Magento even renders the page, but does not take the css style sheets and js files from the parent theme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/skin/frontend/custom_theme/default/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/skin/frontend/custom_theme/default/css/revslider.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/skin/frontend/custom_theme/default/css/jquery.mobile-menu.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/skin/frontend/custom_theme/default/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/skin/frontend/custom_theme/default/css/countdowntimer/countdowntimer.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/skin/frontend/custom_theme/default/css/internal.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/skin/frontend/custom_theme/default/js/revslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/skin/frontend/custom_theme/default/js/common.js"></script>
```

None of these files exist in the child theme, but they exist in the parent theme. Why does not Magento catch them from the parent theme? Am I doing something wrong?

I followed this tutorial: https://www.coderomeos.org/how-to-create-custom-child-theme-in-magento

Thank you very much in advance!